# Pivot for a representation

Tags: excel, vba, pivot-table, visualization

```
       A               B          B    
   1 School ID    Parameter   Score
   2 Sch109          P1       20
   3 Sch109          P2       40       
   4 Sch109          P3       50
   5 Sch109                   110  #Sum of P1, P2,P3 For Sch109
   6 Sch210          P1       10
   7 Sch210          P2       30       
   8 Sch210          P3       90
   9 Sch210                   130   #Sum of P1, P2,P3 For Sch210
   10 Sch100         P1       5
   11 Sch100         P2       20       
   12 Sch100         P3       15
   13 Sch100                  40    #Sum of P1, P2,P3 For Sch100
    
    AND SO ON
```

So basically in this excel all schools have parametersP1, P2, P3 and one row where no parameter is mentioned which is sum of all parameters (P1+P2+P3) which is also shown in comments by #. I need output such that all parameters for one school are in one line.

Expected output:

```
 A             B    C   D   E
1 School ID   P1   P2   P3  Score 
2 Sch109      20   40   50  110
3 Sch210      10   30   90  130
4 Sch100      5    20   15  40
5
```

and so on.

How to do this in excel. With Pivot also I am unable to get desired result

Comment: To do this with a pivot, it would be necessary to remove or filter out the sum rows from the data.

Comment: Which version of excel do you use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have <kbd>Excel365</kbd> then you can do it by <kbd>FILTER()</kbd> and <kbd>XLOOKUP()</kbd> formula.

```
 =FILTER($C$2:$C$13,($A$2:$A$13=$F2)*($B$2:$B$13=G$1),XLOOKUP($F2,$A$2:$A$13,$C$2:$C$13,"",0,-1))
```

[image]

> Edit: Non 365 formula.

For your given dataset you can use `INDEX()/MATCH()` combination. To get `P1`, `P2`, `P3` value per school use following formula to `G2` cell.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH($F2&G$1,$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0))
```

To get Score data use below formula to `J2` cell.

```
=INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH($F2&"",$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0))
```

> If you want to combine above two formula into one then use `IFEEROR()` and use full formula like-

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH($F2&G$1,$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0)),INDEX($C$2:$C$13,MATCH($F2&"",$A$2:$A$13&$B$2:$B$13,0)))
```

[image]

To understand how the formula working then please split each formula to individual cells then observer result one by one.